# If a directory is stored in a variable, what is the correct way to represent its subdirectory when it is quoted?

Tags: bash

For example, given the following variable:

`target=/dir`

If I want to target its subfolder in a command like so:

`rsync "/source/" "/dir/subdir"`

Which of the following is correct?

`rsync "/source/" "$target"/subdir`

`rsync "/source/" "$target/subdir"`

Comment: What do you mean by "delineate"? Have you tried using any of the both ways?

Comment: Both of them should do the same thing. The second one is better looking imo.

Comment: @NicoHaase Perhaps that was poor word choice, I meant, to write.

Comment: Then feel free to edit your question to contain more details

Answer (score 1):

The one below would be a better choice, you have a whole string with a variable to be expanded so using speech marks allows for variable expansion, and a quote would not alow this. Also if there was a space in the next part of the string after your `$target` variable, the command would return with an error. With the speech marks the parameter is run as one parameter.

`rsync "/source/" "$target/subdir"`

Answer (score 0):

> Which of the following is correct?

Both are correct, there is no difference.